# A good implementation for an object that can have 2 or 3 field depending on the type

Tags: java

i think i have a good question regarding the work i'm doing. So i want to create an object to store the type of an HTML element and his xpath. The code is very simple :

```
public class XpathObject {
    private String type;
    private String xpath;

    public XpathObject(String type, String xpath) {

    if(!type.equals("input") && !type.equals("label") && !type.equals("textarea") && !type.equals("button")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

        this.type = type;
        this.xpath = xpath;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getXpath() {
        return xpath;
    }
}
```

The things is that when i have a the "label" type i want this object to have the following 3 fields instead of the 2, type, xpath and xpath_bis. The naive approch woulb be to always put a the xpath_bis and ingore it when i'm not in the "label" case, but i find ugly to have a field setted to null (i might be wrong). How could i implement this case in a proper way. Thanks.

Comment: Create a subclass `XpathLabelObject` which has the extra field, and use the subclass in case type is `"label"`. Maybe create a factory method to create either an instance of `XpathObject` or an instance of `XpathLabelObject` depending on the value of `type`.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't it be a little bit to much to instantiate another object in the class only for this little case ?

Comment: I hesitate for the factory method, i think i will go for it if don't find any other solution

Comment: If you want to have it really simple change your constructor to non parameters and use setter methods.

Comment: @MuratK i don't think this would be a good idea because i could end up with an object not fully initialisated and it disobey the OOP

Comment: @Bob Reynolds You say _"too much only for this little case"_ and talk about OOP.

Comment: Unrelated, but the type should really be an enum, not a String.

Comment: @MuratK what the point of coding in java if it's not to apply the OOP even in the simple exemple ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would be feasible

```
public class XpathObject {
    public final String type; // Or protected final
    public final String xpath;

    public XpathObject(String type, String xpath) { // Or protected
        this.type = type;
        this.xpath = xpath;
    }
}

public class XpathObjectLabel {
    public final String xpathBis;

    public XpathObjectLabel(String xpath, String xpathBis) {
        super("label", xpath);
        this.xpathBis = xpathBis;
    }
}
```

This would make sense if one would make classes XpathObjectTextArea and such.

However as I guess you are creating these objects by parsing text, without much functionality w.r.t. special methods/logic, I think simply putting all in **one single class** would be a good start. With java 8 influence:

```
public class XpathObject {
    public final String type; // Or protected final
    public final String xpath;
    public Optional<String> xpathBis = Optional.empty();

    public XpathObject(String type, String xpath) { // Or protected
        this.type = type;
        this.xpath = xpath;
    }
}
```

Reason: you probably process the DOM elements hierarchically, searching all text inputs (input text + textarea) or whatever. Then you are primarily dealing with XPathObject.

More intelligent things, like what input does this label refer to, require intelligent data structures, Map, an own FieldDefinition class or whatever.
And refactoring is easy.

Comment: The use of the Otional would have been nice ! But i can't use it i'm in java 1.7.I thinks i will go for the first one. PS: you totally guessed what i was doing, i'm impressed

Comment: `Optional<Optional>` so to say. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

First I would suggest to use an enumeration for type instead of a String. This makes it type safe and easily extensible and removes the need for the ugly if statement.

```
public enum ElementType {

INPUT, LABEL, TEXTAREA, BUTTON;
```

}

Second there should be a subclass for type LABEL that has the extra field.

Third I would suggest having Builders that have the appropriat setters and return the correct subtypes, like this:

```
XPathBuilder.builder(LABEL).setXpath("path").setXpathBis("bis").build();
```

and

```
XPathBuilder.builder(TEXTAREA).setXpath("path").build();
```